# Redis, autosave on disk

Tags: php, redis, yii2

Turn off the laptop with no backup and the data stored. Maybe if you pull the battery it will not save) Does Redis upload the data to memory itself?
How to set up auto save after each change? Or is it easier to run a command manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Redis persist data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328317/does-redis-persist-data)

Answer (score 2):

When you turn off a server, if the Redis server is installed as a service and configured correctly with persistence, it should save the data to disk and load it back upon starting up.