# Mongo DB vs Redis insert times. Mongo is faster. Is the below test code fair?

Tags: mongodb, performance, redis, comparison

I am trying to work out if there is benefit to using Redis to cache data.  But MongoDb seems to write data faster. This is with a single Mongo db without replication.

I compare Redis pipe and batch saves, saving 100k rows, to saving to MongoDb, 1 or 100 rows at a time.  I also compare flattening 100 rows into a single document or Redis value for faster saving.

Results:

```
Mongo: Saved 100000 rows, 100 rows at a time, 1564 elapsed milliseconds: 0.01564 ms per row. Num rows inserted: 100000
Redis list pipe Saved 100000 rows to, 100 row at a time, 2030 elapsed milliseconds: 0.0203 ms per row. new listLength: 100000
Redis list batch Saved 100000 rows, 100 row at a time, 2101 elapsed milliseconds: 0.02101 ms per row. new listLength: 100000
Redis list pipe complex Saved 100000 rows to, 10000 rows at a time, total elapsedMilliseconds: 187; 0.00187 ms per row. new listLength: 1000
Mongo: complex Saved 100000 rows, 10000 rows at a time, total 135 elapsed milliseconds: 0.00135 ms per row. Num rows inserted: 1000
```

To run the below C# code, use MSVS 2019 and use Nuget to add StackExchange.Redis, MongoDB.Driver and Newtonsoft.Json.

Conclusion: MongoDb saves faster. Can anyone say why this test is unfair?  I need to know if I'm wrong before we go down the MongoDb path and ignore a caching layer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MongoAndRedisPerformanceTests
{
  public class MGpsDatumJsonComplex
  {
    public MGpsDatumJsonComplex( string pJsonComplex )
    {
      jsonComplex = pJsonComplex;
    }
    public string jsonComplex { get; set; }
  }


  public class MGpsDatum
  {
    public MGpsDatum( int pUnitID, float pX, float pY, DateTime pTimeStamp, byte pSpeedKmph, float? pDistanceKM, DateTime? pTimeInsertedToProviderDb, int pOptionTemplateID )
    {
      ID = -1;
      UnitID = pUnitID;
      X = pX;
      Y = pY;
      TimeStamp = pTimeStamp;
      SpeedKmph = pSpeedKmph;
      DistanceKM = pDistanceKM;
      TimeInsertedToProviderDb = pTimeInsertedToProviderDb;
      OptionTemplateID = pOptionTemplateID;
      extRef = "1000000000";
    }

    public string extRef { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int UnitID { get; set; }

    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public float? DistanceKM { get; set; }

    public byte SpeedKmph { get; set; }

    public int? OptionTemplateID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeInsertedToProviderDb { get; set; }

    public float? OdoKm { get; set; }        

    public float? AuxFloat1 { get; set; }   

    public bool HasStoppedOrAtStopStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeSavedToOSGPSdb { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void MongoDataSaveSpeedTest()
    {
      MongoClientSettings mongo_settings = new MongoClientSettings();

      mongo_settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress( "127.0.0.1" );

      MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient( mongo_settings );

      IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase( "OpsiService" );
      IMongoCollection<MGpsDatum> posCollection = db.GetCollection<MGpsDatum>( "GpsDataSpeedTest" );

      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
      int numRows = 10000;
      for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
      {
        posCollection.InsertOne( gpsDatum );
      }
      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;  
      Console.WriteLine( "Saved " + numRows + " rows to Mongo collection, 1 row at a time, " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds: " + ((float) ((float) elapsedMilliseconds)/ ((float) numRows ) ) + " ms per row." );
      int br = 0;
    }

    static void MongoDataSaveSpeedTest_MultiInsert( int numRows, int batchSize )
    {
      MongoClientSettings mongo_settings = new MongoClientSettings();
      mongo_settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress( "127.0.0.1" );
      MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient( mongo_settings );
      IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase( "OpsiService" );
      db.DropCollection( "GpsDataSpeedTest" );

      IMongoCollection<MGpsDatum> posCollection = db.GetCollection<MGpsDatum>( "GpsDataSpeedTest" );
      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      List<MGpsDatum> listGpsDatum = new List<MGpsDatum>( batchSize );
      for (int i=0; i< batchSize; i++)
      {
        listGpsDatum.Add( gpsDatum );
      }

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

      for (int i = 0; i < numRows/batchSize; i++)
      {
        posCollection.InsertMany( listGpsDatum );
      }
      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds; 
      long numRowsAfterInsert = posCollection.CountDocuments( FilterDefinition<MGpsDatum>.Empty );

      Console.WriteLine( "Mongo: Saved " + numRows + " rows, " + batchSize + " rows at a time, " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds: " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. Num rows inserted: " + numRowsAfterInsert );
    }

    static void MongoDataSaveSpeedTest_MultiInsert_complex( int numRows, int batchSize, int numRowsInRecord )
    {
      MongoClientSettings mongo_settings = new MongoClientSettings();
      mongo_settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress( "127.0.0.1" );
      MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient( mongo_settings );
      IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase( "OpsiService" );
      db.DropCollection( "GpsDataSpeedTestComplex" );

      IMongoCollection<MGpsDatumJsonComplex> posCollection = db.GetCollection<MGpsDatumJsonComplex>( "GpsDataSpeedTestComplex" );
      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      List<MGpsDatum> complexGpsDatum = new List<MGpsDatum>( numRowsInRecord );
      for (int i=0; i<numRowsInRecord; i++)
      {
        complexGpsDatum.Add( gpsDatum );
      }
      List<MGpsDatumJsonComplex> listComplexGpsDatum = new List<MGpsDatumJsonComplex>( batchSize );
      string complextGpsDatumStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( complexGpsDatum );
      MGpsDatumJsonComplex complexJson = new MGpsDatumJsonComplex( complextGpsDatumStr );
      for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
      {
        listComplexGpsDatum.Add( complexJson );
      }

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

      for (int i = 0; i < numRows / (batchSize*numRowsInRecord ) ; i++)
      {
        posCollection.InsertMany( listComplexGpsDatum );
      }
      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
      long numRowsAfterInsert = posCollection.CountDocuments( FilterDefinition<MGpsDatumJsonComplex>.Empty );

      Console.WriteLine( "Mongo: complex Saved " + numRows + " rows, " + batchSize*numRowsInRecord + " rows at a time, total " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds: " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. Num rows inserted: " + numRowsAfterInsert );
    }

    //  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796054/pipelining-vs-batching-in-stackexchange-redis
    static void RedisSaveSpeedTest_Pipelining( int numRows, int batchSize )
    {
      ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect( "localhost:6379,connectTimeout=20000" );
      IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase( 1 );
      db.KeyDelete( "GpsTestQueue" );

      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      string gpsDatumJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( gpsDatum );

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

      for (int b = 0; b < numRows / batchSize; b++)
      {
        List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
          Task<long> addAsync = db.ListLeftPushAsync( "GpsTestQueue", gpsDatumJson );
          addTasks.Add( addAsync );
        }
        Task[] tasks = addTasks.ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll( tasks );
      }  

      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;  
      long listLength = db.ListLength( "GpsTestQueue" );
      Console.WriteLine( "Redis list pipe Saved " + numRows + " rows to, " + batchSize + " row at a time, " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds: " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. new listLength: " + listLength );
    }

    //  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796054/pipelining-vs-batching-in-stackexchange-redis
    static void RedisSaveSpeedTest_Batching( int numRows, int batchSize )
    {
      ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect( "localhost:6379,connectTimeout=20000" );
      IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase( 1 );
      db.KeyDelete( "GpsTestQueue" );

      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      string gpsDatumJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( gpsDatum );

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

      for (int b = 0; b < numRows / batchSize; b++)
      {
        List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
        IBatch batch = db.CreateBatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
          Task<long> addAsync = db.ListLeftPushAsync( "GpsTestQueue", gpsDatumJson );
          addTasks.Add( addAsync );
        }
        batch.Execute();
        Task[] tasks = addTasks.ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll( tasks );
      }

      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;  
      long listLength = db.ListLength( "GpsTestQueue" );
      Console.WriteLine( "Redis list batch Saved " + numRows + " rows, " + batchSize + " row at a time, " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds: " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. new listLength: " + listLength );
    }

    static void RedisSaveSpeedTest_Pipelining_complex( int numRows, int batchSize, int numRowsInRecord )
    {
      ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect( "localhost:6379,connectTimeout=20000" );
      IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase( 1 );
      db.KeyDelete( "GpsTestQueue" );

      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      string gpsDatumJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( gpsDatum );
      string gpsDatumJsonComplex = "";
      for (int i=0; i < numRowsInRecord; i++)
      {
        gpsDatumJsonComplex += gpsDatumJson;
      }

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

      int numBatchSaves = numRows / (numRowsInRecord * batchSize);
      for (int b = 0; b < numBatchSaves; b++)
      {
        List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
          Task<long> addAsync = db.ListLeftPushAsync( "GpsTestQueue", gpsDatumJsonComplex );
          addTasks.Add( addAsync );
        }
        Task[] tasks = addTasks.ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll( tasks );
      }

      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
      long listLength = db.ListLength( "GpsTestQueue" );
      Console.WriteLine( "Redis list pipe complex Saved " + numRows + " rows to, " + batchSize* numRowsInRecord + " rows at a time, total elapsedMilliseconds: " + elapsedMilliseconds + "; " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. new listLength: " + listLength );
    }

    static void RedisSaveSpeedTest()
    {
      ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect( "localhost:6379,connectTimeout=20000" );
      IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase( 1 );
      db.KeyDelete( "GpsTestQueue" );
      MGpsDatum gpsDatum = new MGpsDatum( 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, null, DateTime.Now, 1 );
      string gpsDatumJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( gpsDatum );

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
      int numRows = 10000;
      for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
      {
        db.ListLeftPush( "GpsTestQueue", gpsDatumJson );
      }
      int elapsedMilliseconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;  
      long listLength = db.ListLength( "GpsTestQueue" );
      Console.WriteLine( "batch Saved " + numRows + " rows to Redis collection, 1 row at a time, " + elapsedMilliseconds + " elapsed milliseconds. " + ((float)((float)elapsedMilliseconds) / ((float)numRows)) + " ms per row. new listLength: " + listLength );

      int br = 0;
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      //MongoDataSaveSpeedTest();
      //RedisSaveSpeedTest();

      int batchSize = 100;
      int numRows = 100000;
      int numRowsInRecord = 100;

      MongoDataSaveSpeedTest_MultiInsert( numRows, batchSize );

      RedisSaveSpeedTest_Pipelining( numRows, batchSize );

      RedisSaveSpeedTest_Batching( numRows, batchSize );

      RedisSaveSpeedTest_Pipelining_complex( numRows, batchSize, numRowsInRecord );

      MongoDataSaveSpeedTest_MultiInsert_complex( numRows, batchSize, numRowsInRecord );

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `InsertOne()` is certainly a bad idea. `Bulk.insert()` would be the proper way for inserting massive data. Even `InsertMany()` inserts the data one by one.

Comment: Mongodb doesn't save data to disk immediately. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#standalone Repeat your tests with enough pressure on memory DB side, populate collections with data.

Comment: For proper testing, I think the test should run at least several seconds, maybe one Minute.

Comment: Redis also doesn't save to disk always: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328317/does-redis-persist-data

Comment: Of course not. My point is there is no reason to assume Mongo should always be slower than Redis. Again - test it with full-size db. The results may surprise you.